# SmartGWT TreeGrid Datasource filled by nested array JSON

Tags: json, gwt, datasource, smartgwt, treegrid

I have tried to do the same as the sample says but using JSON instead of XML

[Smart GWT Tree](http://www.smartclient.com/index.jsp?skin=SmartGWT#treeLoadXML)

When i do it using XML, it works perfectly, but it only loads first childs when i use JSON.

Here is the XML:

```
<response>
<errors />
<data>
    <project>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Checho Project</name>
        <sprints>
            <project>
                <id>4</id>
                <name>Backlog</name>
            </project>
        </sprints>
    </project>
</data>
</response>
```

And here is the JSON:

```
{"response":
   {"errors":"","data":
     {"project":[{"id":1,"name":"Bee Project","sprints":
                                                 {"project":[{"id":3,"name":"sprint3"},{"id":4,"name":"sprint2"},{"id":2,"name":"sprint1"}]}},
                    {"id":5,"name":"Checho Project","sprints":
                                                  {"project":{"id":6,"name":"Backlog"}}}]
     }
   }
}
```

---

```
private ProjectDS(String id) {

    setID(id);
    setRecordXPath("/response/data/*");
    // setRecordXPath("/Employees/*");
    // DataSourceTextField nameField = new DataSourceTextField("Name", "Name", 128);
    //
    // DataSourceIntegerField employeeIdField = new DataSourceIntegerField("EmployeeId", "Employee ID");
    // employeeIdField.setPrimaryKey(true);
    // employeeIdField.setRequired(true);

    DataSourceTextField idField = new DataSourceTextField("id", "Id", 128, true);
    idField.setHidden(true);
    idField.setPrimaryKey(true);

    DataSourceTextField itemNameField = new DataSourceTextField("name", "Item", 128, true);

    DataSourceField reportsToField = new DataSourceField();
    reportsToField.setName("sprints");
    reportsToField.setChildrenProperty(true);

    setFields(idField, itemNameField, reportsToField);

    setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);
    setDataURL("bee_gui/sc/ds.xml");
    setClientOnly(true);

}
```

Did anyone deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JSON object in this fashion then you will get the solution

```
{"List":
    {"employee":
        [{"EmployeeId":4,"ReportsTo":1,"Name":"Seg 1", "Job":"Chief Operating Officer","Salary":260000},{"EmployeeId":192,"ReportsTo":4,"Name":"Leg 1","Job":"Mgr Cap Rptg Dist","Salary":460000},{"EmployeeId":5,"ReportsTo":1,"Name":"Seg 2", "Job":"Chief Operating Officer","Salary":260000},{"EmployeeId":193,"ReportsTo":5,"Name":"Leg 2","Job":"Mgr Cap Rptg Dist","Salary":460000}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use "Javascript Overly Types" for my JSON parsing

Take a look here, if you want to know more: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html

They are pretty easy an work really well!

PS: Sry that I can't help you with your example...